# Перенос целых слов в CSS

Tags: css

Есть блок меню, реализуемый через список. Есть пункт, состоящий из нескольких слов. В адаптивном режиме название пункта не помещается в одну строку, одно из слов переносится на другую строку, причем перенос внутри самого слова. Каким образом можно реализовать перенос по пробелам, причем только в адаптивном режиме?

Конкретно: фраза "неправомерное обобщение нехарактерных явлений" переносится как, например: "неправомерное обобщение нехак- (перевод строки)
терных явлений". Word-break убирает значок переноса, но не решает проблему. желательно, чтобы переносилось как "неправомерное обобщение (перевод строки) нехарактерных явлений"

Answer (score 2):

Есть свойство для этого `word-break` со значением `break-all`

```css
.wrap{
width: 220px;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid red;
word-break: break-all;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
Honorificabilitudinitatibus califragilisticexpialidocious Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu 次の単語グレートブリテンおよび北アイルランド連合王国で本当に大きな言葉
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: ссылка может "пропасть" из интернета, приведите рабочий пример в ответе

Comment: @meine дополнил ответ